# Switching player with ternary operator

Tags: javascript

The dice rolls and its sum adds up in "Current" area of player 1. When the dice rolls 1, it is the turn of player 2. At this stage I am working on the switching player. Ternary operator is used and it is fired along with `console.log('change'), but it does not switch and it shows an error on browser console:

```
script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:12)
```

and on snippets:

```
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 133,
  "colno": 66
```

```js
document.querySelector('.dice_img').classList.add('hidden') //no dot in here
const scores = [0, 0];
let scoreT = 0;
let activePlayer = 0;
document.querySelector(".roll_dice").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.dice_img').classList.remove('hidden')
  let rndm = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
  document.querySelector('.dice_img').src = `dice-${rndm}.png`
  if (rndm !== 1) {
    scoreT += rndm;
    document.querySelector(`.current_${activePlayer}`).textContent = scoreT
  } else {
    activePlayer = activePlayer === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    console.log('change')
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rndm {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  /*align-content: center;*/
}

.player_0 {
  background-color: chocolate;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.player_0,
.player_1 {
  height: 70%;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.player_1 {
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.buttons {
  padding: 4rem;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.btnF {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(80, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.dice_img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>pig game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="rndm"></h1>
  <main>
    <section class="player_0">
      <div class="up">
        <h2>Player 1</h2>
        <h1 class="score_0">0</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="down">
        <h3>Current</h3>
        <p class="current_0">0</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="player_1">
      <div class="up">
        <h2>Player 2</h2>
        <h1 class="score_1">0</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="down">
        <h3>Current</h3>
        <p class="score_1">0</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="new_game btnF">New Game</button>
      <img src="dice-1.png" alt="Playing dice" class='dice_img' srcset="">
      <button class="roll_dice btnF">Roll Dice</button>
      <button class="hold btnF">Hold</button>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had typo in class name. You had "score_1" instead of "current_1"

```js
document.querySelector('.dice_img').classList.add('hidden') //no dot in here
const scores = [0, 0];
let scoreT = 0;
let activePlayer = 0;
document.querySelector(".roll_dice").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.dice_img').classList.remove('hidden')
  let rndm = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
  document.querySelector('.dice_img').src = `dice-${rndm}.png`
  if (rndm !== 1) {
    scoreT += rndm;
    document.querySelector(`.current_${activePlayer}`).textContent = scoreT
  } else {
    activePlayer = activePlayer === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    console.log('change')
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rndm {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  /*align-content: center;*/
}

.player_0 {
  background-color: chocolate;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.player_0,
.player_1 {
  height: 70%;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.player_1 {
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.buttons {
  padding: 4rem;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.btnF {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(80, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.dice_img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>pig game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="rndm"></h1>
  <main>
    <section class="player_0">
      <div class="up">
        <h2>Player 1</h2>
        <h1 class="score_0">0</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="down">
        <h3>Current</h3>
        <p class="current_0">0</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="player_1">
      <div class="up">
        <h2>Player 2</h2>
        <h1 class="score_1">0</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="down">
        <h3>Current</h3>
        <p class="current_1">0</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="new_game btnF">New Game</button>
      <img src="dice-1.png" alt="Playing dice" class='dice_img' srcset="">
      <button class="roll_dice btnF">Roll Dice</button>
      <button class="hold btnF">Hold</button>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't post a full answer for a simple typo. Post a comment and flag it for closing.